# Convert Hours to a time java

Tags: java, time

What is the best way to convert hours into the time.

Lets say 5 hours and current time is 9:17am

Now if I run the app the time should be 0417 (am)

Thanks

Comment: run the app = current time - hours?

Comment: Do you want to set the system time? Or just compute timestamps?

Comment: I don't get why people down-vote the questions ? If you don't know the answer just bugger off.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence to do that based on current time:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9 );
cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 17 );

cal.add( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -5 );
System.out.println( cal.getTime() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `DateObject` like this:

```
Date time5HoursBefore = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() - 5 * 3600000 ); //3600000 is the number of milliseconds per hour
```

An alternative would be using Apache Commons' `DateUtils`:

```
Date time5HoursBefore = DateUtils.addHours(new Date(), -5);
```